# How do I algebraically change the integration limits of double integrals when substituting variables without looking at the plot?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, substitution

So, lets say I have a pretty regular 2 units radius circle:

$$
x^2+y^2=4
$$

If I want to calculate the area:

$$
\int_{-2}^{2}dy \int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} dx = 4\pi
$$

So let's say I want to switch it to polars:

$$
x=r\cos(\theta)
$$$$
y=r\sin(\theta)
$$$$
J = \begin{vmatrix}x_r & y_r\\x_\theta & y_\theta\end{vmatrix} = r
$$

So we normally would just do it like this:

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{2} rdr = 4\pi
$$

But here is the problem, is there a way to obtain the integration limits $ 0, 2\pi $ and $ 0, 2 $ without actually knowing how the integration region looks like?

I tried the following

$$
y = 2
$$$$
r\sin(\theta)=2
$$$$
\theta = \arcsin(2/r)
$$

And with $r$

$$
x=\sqrt{4-y^2}
$$$$
r\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{4-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}
$$$$
r=2
$$

I'm not entirely sure how to find $r$ for the lower limit (or the upper for that case), because I actually end up with the same absolute value. So I just tried with $r=\pm2$:

$$
\int_{-2}^{2} dr \int_{\arcsin(-2/r)}^{\arcsin(2/r)} rd\theta
$$

And if I plug that into Wolfram Alpha I get $2\pi$ which is not exactly what I was looking for, but at least it's coherent.

But the point is, how do I get to $ 0, 2\pi $ and $ 0, 2 $ without actually looking at the plot?

Comment: To get $r$ you should use $x^2+y^2\leq 4$, which gives $r\leq 2$. And by definition $r\geq 0$.